# JQL: Get list of sprints

Tags: jira, jql

Is it possible to get a list of sprints for a particular project ? I know there is a way to find issues by a sprint, but haven't found any way to get all the sprints.

Comment: Are you using JQL in JIRA or in some application. AFAIK, JQL only returns Issues as results.

Comment: Using it via their API.

Answer (score 17):

I use the following rest call to find all the sprints:

https://yourjira.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/integration/teamcalendars/sprint/list?jql=project+%3D+YOURPROJECTKEY

To find only the open sprint of the project I run this:
https://yourjira.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/integration/teamcalendars/sprint/list?jql=project+%3D+YOURPROJECTKEY+and+Sprint+not+in+closedSprints()

Comment: Is there any documentation to refer?

Comment: how can I find the last closed sprint? tried using ORDER BY updatedDate DESC but this returns all the closed sprints.

Answer (score 11):

In JQL it's not yet possible but you can use the new jira agile API. Here is the documentation for [jira cloud](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/cloud/) and for [jira server 7.2.3](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/7.2.3/).

First, you need to find the board of your project. This REST endpoint to get the list of your boards is:

`[jira-url]/rest/agile/1.0/board`

Next you can get their project with:

`[jira-url]/rest/agile/1.0/[board-id]/project`

So in this manner you can find the board id of your project. At the end, you can get the sprints list of this board with:

`[jira-url]/rest/agile/1.0/[board-id]/sprint`

Comment: thank you... however... it seems like it's actually: [jira-url]/rest/agile/1.0/board/[board-id]/sprint   When I use that, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

```
[jira-url]/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprint/picker
```

Delivers "allMatches" array containing active sprints including id and boardName.

It was useful to me when i was searching a list of active sprints in all projects to clean up not completed or not well named sprints.

Answer (score 5):

Based on this answer: [answers.atlassian.com/questions/65920/answers/3599592](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/65920/answers/3599592), the best Web API to get the list of sprints is:

```
https://<your_site>/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprintquery/<rapidBoardId>?includeFutureSprints=true&includeHistoricSprints=false
```

`<rapidBoardId>` is different in each system, I just saw it in the address bar of my browser when I was surfing in JIRA, then I hard coded it into the code which is calling the API.

```
https://<your_site>/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=<rapidBoardId is here on your browser address bar>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no REST endpoint to do this, you can only query the sprints that are visible for a particular Rapid Board and you need to use the GreenHoppper plugin for this.

The endpoint for that is: https://yourjira.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprints/{rapidBoardId}

You can enumerate the Rapid Boards at another REST endpoint: https://yourjira.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/rapidviews/list

Read more here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/65920/how-can-i-list-all-sprints-from-greenhopper-using-the-rest-api

Answer (score 2):

There is no straightforward solution, only workarounds. What is ridiculous why Jira doesn't provide such API calls.

You can use this endpoint:

```
https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/{cloudId}/rest/api/2/jql/autocompletedata/suggestions?fieldName=Sprint&fieldValue=
```

Take notice of whitespace character on the end of query. It implies that every name of sprint includes whitespace char inside.

Output:

```json
    {
        "results": [
            {
                "value": "2",
                "displayName": "Sprint 4 - 2020-06-17 04:00 (12)"
            },
            {
                "value": "1",
                "displayName": "Sprint 2 - 2020-06-20 06:45 (6)"
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not invent this, a colleague did. However, you can easily access all of the sprints in the "search issues" screen by using this JQL: Sprint is not EMPTY

That's it. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the sprint report? The dropdown will show you a list of all sprints for that board. Of course you can have multiple boards per project, so you might need to search all related boards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

1. call `rest/api/2/search?jql=project%20%3D%20ABCD%20AND%20Sprint%20in%20openSprints()` to get the issues in current active sprint. Then you could get the active sprint.
2. make another call `rest/api/2/search?jql=Sprint%20%3D%2014343` to get the issues.

Below the code to parse the active sprint.

```js
fetch(sprintUrl, {
      headers: requestHeader,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const regex = new RegExp("state=ACTIVE");
        let activeSprint = data.issues[0].fields.customfield_14400.filter(
          (e: string) => regex.test(e)
        )[0];
        const sprintParser =
          /id=(\d+).*?name=(.*?),startDate=([\d-]+).*?endDate=([\d-]+)/g;
        const group = [...activeSprint.matchAll(sprintParser)][0];
        setSprint(
          Object.create({
            id: parseInt(group[1]),
            name: group[2],
            startDate: group[3],
            endDate: group[4],
          })
        );
      });
```