# Linking project and board together with Jira API

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

I'm working on an app which includes the Jira API (and agile API).

I need a list of projects (this is no problem), I use :

https://example.com/rest/api/latest/project?projectKey=TA

and then I need to be able to click on a project and give me a list of sprints + issues for each sprint. Here I am stuck. I have found another related question ([JQL: Get list of sprints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380919/jql-get-list-of-sprints)), which gives me a list of sprints based on a projectkey, by using :

https://example.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/integration/teamcalendars/sprint/list?jql=project+%3D+TA”

However, I don't know how to get the issues for said sprint.

I also know how to get the issues for a sprint directly from the agile API : https://example.com/rest/agile/latest/board/5/sprint/4/issue

but I can't seem to link the board to the projectkey.

I have found a similar topics on the atlassian site itself, but they usually mention there is no REST endpoint to do what I want. Although I'm sure it should be possible (?).

The answers I find elsewhere, I don't really understand (filter on rapidId's or something similar) so I really need a noob-explanation of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue, but I have found a way to get the board and sprint id(s) needed to get the sprint details. I'd like to improve this as it depends on string matching the board name (which you may not have) to the project.

You can get all the rapidview ids here:
https://example.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/rapidview

Assuming you have a standard naming convention for boards this will work, buts its a big If.

https://example.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprintquery/
will give you the sprints.

Interested to see if anyone else have found a better way to do this!